# How to import node module in Angular?

Tags: node.js, angular, typescript, node-modules

I'm developing an Angular app. 
For some reason I want to use `querystring.escape()`.
I wrote `import { escape } from 'querystring'`, but I got `querystring.escape is not a function` error.
How can I import a node module in typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are destructuring `querystring` trying to get the escape property, but then you want to call `querystring.escape()` which you haven't imported.

What you want to do is this:

`import * as querystring from 'querystring';`

or

`import querystring from 'querystring'`